# How to parse large text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a large text file. The text file is not actually a XML file.   The tags which look like this:

```
<tag1>
<tagsomedata> text1 </tagsomedata>
<text> text some pattern1 </text>
</tag1>
<tag1>
<tagsomedata> text2 </tagsomedata>
<text> text some pattern2 </text>
</tag1>
```

and so on.. 

I need output in the form :

text1 pattern1

text2 pattern2

I used BeautifulSoup and it worked for a shorter file well. I was reading the file as filetext=open(filename).read(). For larger original file it gave segmentation fault 11 error.

I can not read my file in some fixed sizes as the tags can get split. I need to read the file tagwise. In above example I will iterate through "tag1" and get required values of every subtag.

I also tried xml.etree.ElementTree but it requires well parsed XML. I tried manually changing some obvious unwanted tags from XML file but it still gave error "mismatched tag". I have such 100+ files and I can not manually change each file.

 
Please let me know what can be done in this case?

Comment: Could you provide the sample contents on which `BeautifulSoup` failed?

Comment: Yes :  I read the file  
filetext=open(filename).read() <br/>
soup = BeautifulSoup(filetext) <br/>
for doc in soup.find_all('tag1'):

Comment: Can you be more specific about how the file is not valid XML? Also give some real sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is very large and as structured as you've shown, you can simply read in the file a data tag (`<tag1>.*?</1tag1>`, not markup tag) at a time and run a regex against it. Advantages of this approach are that it is very fast to implement, fast to run, and can be resilient against file corruption. Disadvantages include that can be brittle if you have complex, nested XML.

A more flexible approach is to use a SAX parser if you have properly formed XML. Advantages of this approach is that it is more flexible, more portable, and, when compared to other XML parsers, has reduced memory requirements. Disadvantages include that it can be slower to run - a consideration if you have say TBs of data to parse.

Comment: `f.read()` will read the entire file all into memory at once.

Comment: Using `re` on a XML file is inherently dangerous, because XML natively supports  hierarchical inclusion of same tag (`<tag>...<tag>text</tag>...</tag>`) and `re` does not - it may be acceptable here but you should warn future readers of that.

Comment: @jamylak - Thanks for mentioning that. The example is updated now.

Comment: I've messed with large XML files on various projects and I've never come across a situation where regular expressions were the solution. They're too brittle and not sufficiently future proof to be worth it. I have used regexps to parse textual data between tags but that's always after parsing the actual XML.

Comment: I agree regex is brittle and SAX is the ideal way to go but sometimes when you have GBs of data to parse, it's well formed, and you are under a deadline, it can work. I've successfully used this approach for TBs of XML without issue but caveat emptor.

Comment: The SAX API is very mechanical. You can write a tiny script to generate a SAX based parser in a fraction of the time to write and debug a regexp. The need to meet a deadline, in my opinion, is an argument in favour of using SAX over a regular expression but, like you said, YMMV. Always great to have options though. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is a well formed huge XML file, you can use one of the [SAX](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.html) APIs in Python. This is alternative to the DOM api which allows you to incrementally parse the file without loading it all up into memory. The API requires you to implement a callback for every tag opening and closing. You can use this to build collect data into your final data structure and get the whole thing done without reading the entire file into memory (which is what I think most of the DOM based APIs do).